# Adding a constant value to pyomo objective after creating the objective expression

Tags: python, expression, constants, pyomo

I got a pyomo model with an objective can be seen as follows:

```
model.objective.pprint()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
None :   True : minimize : 50*InvestmentFlow.invest[pv1,bus_pv] - 
                           9*flow[bus_pv,grid_exp,0] - 
                           9*flow[bus_pv,grid_exp,1] - 
                           9*flow[bus_pv,grid_exp,2]
```

I would like to add a constant into this objective expression like lets say 3000, after creating the model (but before solving it). Is something like that possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the answer, following adds the constant value into the objective function

```
model.objective.expr.__add__(3000)
```